# Use regexes to reformat a reference title in a BibTeX file

Tags: text-processing, regex

I have many references in a BibTeX file as follows:

```
@inproceedings{lechartier2014static,
  title={Static and Dynamic Modeling of a PEMFC for Prognostics Purpose},
  author={Lechartier, Elodie and Gouriveau, Rafael and Pera, Marie-Cecile and Hissel, Daniel and Zerhouni, Noureddine},
  booktitle={Vehicle Power and Propulsion Conference (VPPC), 2014 IEEE},
  pages={1--5},
  year={2014},
  organization={IEEE}
}
@inproceedings{zein2013statistical,
  title={Statistical approach to online prognostics of turbine engine components},
  author={Zein-Sabatto, Saleh and Bodruzzaman, Jabir and Mikhail, Mervat},
  booktitle={Southeastcon, 2013 Proceedings of IEEE},
  pages={1--6},
  year={2013},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

[Link to the original file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12761606/) (the number of spaces in front of each `title=` entry varies).

How can I use regexes to change all the title part to be:

```
  title={\textbf{Static and Dynamic Modeling of a PEMFC for Prognostics Purpose}},
```

Comment: You should really modify the Bibliography style instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\( *\)title=\(.*\),/\1title={\\textbf\2},/' in
```

To edit the file inplace instead of printing the edited file to `stdout`, add the `-i` option:

```
sed -i 's/^\( *\)title=\(.*\),/\1title={\\textbf\2},/' in
```

- `\( *\)`: matches and groups any number of  characters at the start of the line;
- `title=`: matches a `^title=` string;
- `\(.*\),`: matches and groups any number of any character before a `,` character greedily and a `,` character;
- `title={\\textbf\1},`: replaces the match with a `title={\textbf` string followed by the captured group followed by a `},` string;

```
% cat in
@inproceedings{lechartier2014static,
  title={Static and Dynamic Modeling of a PEMFC for Prognostics Purpose},
  author={Lechartier, Elodie and Gouriveau, Rafael and Pera, Marie-Cecile and Hissel, Daniel and Zerhouni, Noureddine},
  booktitle={Vehicle Power and Propulsion Conference (VPPC), 2014 IEEE},
  pages={1--5},
  year={2014},
  organization={IEEE}
}
@inproceedings{zein2013statistical,
  title={Statistical approach to online prognostics of turbine engine components},
  author={Zein-Sabatto, Saleh and Bodruzzaman, Jabir and Mikhail, Mervat},
  booktitle={Southeastcon, 2013 Proceedings of IEEE},
  pages={1--6},
  year={2013},
  organization={IEEE}
}
% sed 's/^\( *\)title=\(.*\),/\1title={\\textbf\2},/' in
@inproceedings{lechartier2014static,
  title={\textbf{Static and Dynamic Modeling of a PEMFC for Prognostics Purpose}},
  author={Lechartier, Elodie and Gouriveau, Rafael and Pera, Marie-Cecile and Hissel, Daniel and Zerhouni, Noureddine},
  booktitle={Vehicle Power and Propulsion Conference (VPPC), 2014 IEEE},
  pages={1--5},
  year={2014},
  organization={IEEE}
}
@inproceedings{zein2013statistical,
  title={\textbf{Statistical approach to online prognostics of turbine engine components}},
  author={Zein-Sabatto, Saleh and Bodruzzaman, Jabir and Mikhail, Mervat},
  booktitle={Southeastcon, 2013 Proceedings of IEEE},
  pages={1--6},
  year={2013},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

Comment: Your regex fails to handle commas in a title. Running `sed 's/^title=\([^,]*\)/title={\\textbf\1}/'` on a title with a comma messes it up: *title={Static and Dynamic Modeling, and of a PEMFC for Prognostics Purpose},* is transformed into *title={\textbf{Static and Dynamic Modeling}, and of a PEMFC for Prognostics Purpose},*

Comment: Nope, not fixed. Now it messes up all lines, comma or not. Running your new regex `sed 's/^title=\(.*,\)/title={\\textbf\1}/'` transforms *title={Static and Dynamic Modeling of a PEMFC for Prognostics Purpose},* to *title={\textbf{Static and Dynamic Modeling of a PEMFC for Prognostics Purpose},}*.

Comment: @A.P. Absolutely. I'm probably tired because I didn't made a single thing right until now. Should be ok now, thanks

Comment: No problem. Seems to work now.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the techniques worked. How can I submit the original file? No attachment is allowed here. Thx

Comment: @OOzyPal Worked fine on my end. Perhaps you have windows line endings? If so, run `dos2unix` on your file first. You can also share your file on dropbox or something, I can take a look.

Comment: @OOzyPal What A.P. said, both solutions should work. I suspect your problem is this one: you have carriage returns in your input file (Windows line-ending), and this breaks A.P.'s solution, because it expects a `,` before the newline, but your file has a carriage return between the `,` and the newline;

Comment: @OOzyPal Nonetheless you probably ran my solution without the `-i` switch, which prints the output to `stdout`. Either run a slighly modified version of A.P.'s solution (`perl -i -pe 's|^(title=)(.+?)(,)\r$|$1\{\\textbf$2\}$3|' file.txt` should do) or run my second solution (`sed -i 's/^title=\(.*\),/title={\\textbf\1},/' in`)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. Here you go: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zrsl1xfkpp2niyh/ProgRef.bib?dl=0
Thank you all

Comment: @OOzyPal You have carriage returns in your file, `head -n 1 ProgRef.bib | hexdump -c` shows a carriage return before the newline. Read A.P.'s last comment or my last comment for options / instructions on how to fix this.

Comment: @OOzyPal Yep, carriage returns. Please see my updated answer above for instructions.

Comment: Gentlemen,  still did not work. I changed the file dos2unix and still did not work. I checked the end of the file and found only \n. I also tried unix2dos and found the end of the file is \r \n and still did not work.  I am sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @OOzyPal No bothering, I think there might be other weird characters in the lines. Can you add the output of `head -n 1 ProgRef.bib | hexdump -c` to the question?

Comment: @OOzyPal I found the problem: the problem is that in your original file you have (seemingly always) a variable number of spaces before each `title=[...]` entry; I updated my answer, it should work on your original file now.

Comment: This Worked OK.

Answer (score 3):

This works fine:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's|^(\s*title=)(.+?)(,)$|$1\{\\textbf$2\}$3|' ProgRef.bib
```

This reformats all title parts and assumes there's just one title per line. It also does a backup of your file (with the `.bak` extension).

Update: If your input file has DOS/Windows line endings, do this:

1. `sudo apt-get install dos2unix`
2. `dos2unix ProgRef.bib`
3. run the above regex

Comment: Why would it break the command if the trailing comma is anchored by `$`? Just tested with a comma in the title, works fine. Did you test my regex? If so, you got a test case to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: That's all right, but you need to fix your regex regarding the commas, too. See my comment above.

Comment: Yep, this was by design, but on second thought, I changed it to leave the leading whitespaces alone.